# Connecting to Google cloud mysql instance from GKE cluster using cloudsqlproxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-sql-proxy

I have two projects in GCP viz. `project1` and `project2`

I have setup `mysql` instance in project1.

I have also setup `cloudsqlproxy` (pod) and `mypod` in a GKE cluster in `project2.
I want to access mysql instance from`mypod`through`cloudsqlproxy`.

I have the following code for `cloudmysqlproxy`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cloudsqlproxy-service-mainnet
  namespace: dev
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: port-mainnet
  selector:
    app: cloudsqlproxy

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cloudsqlproxy
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cloudsqlproxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cloudsqlproxy
    spec:
      containers:
       # Make sure to specify image tag in production
       # Check out the newest version in release page
       # https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/releases
      - name: cloudsqlproxy
        image: b.gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:latest
       # 'Always' if imageTag is 'latest', else set to 'IfNotPresent'
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: cloudsqlproxy
        command:
        - /cloud_sql_proxy
        - -dir=/cloudsql
        - -instances=project1:asia-east1:development=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306
        - -credential_file=/credentials/credentials.json
        ports:
        - name: port-mainnet
          containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /cloudsql
          name: cloudsql
        - mountPath: /credentials
          name: cloud-sql-client-account-token
      volumes:
      - name: cloudsql
        emptyDir:
      - name: cloud-sql-client-account-token
        secret:
          secretName: cloud-sql-client-account-token
```

I have setup `cloud-sql-client-account-token` in the following manner:

```
kubectl create secret cloud-sql-client-account-token --from-file=credentials.json=$HOME/credentials.json
```

Where I downloaded the `credentials.json` file from a service account in `project1`.

When I try to access the mysql instance from my pod, I get the folløwing error:

```
mysql --host=cloudsqlproxy-service-mainnet.dev.svc.cluster.local --port=3306
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'cloudsqlproxy~35.187.201.86' (using password: NO)
```

And the `cloud-proxy` logs, I get the following:

```
2018/11/25 00:35:31 Instance project1:asia-east1:development closed connection
```

Is it necessary to launch a mysql instance in the same project (`project2`) as the pod? What am I missing?

## EDIT

I can access the proxy on my local machine by setting up like this

```
/cloud_sql_proxy -instances=project1:asia-east1:development=tcp:3306
```

and then connecting to the proxy using a mysql client.